# Why are my uniform locations showing incorrectly?

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I'm attempting to get the uniform locations of variables in my shader.

```
@Override
public void getAllUniformLocations(){
    location_transformationMatrix = super.getUniformLocation("transformationMatrix");
    location_lightPosition = super.getUniformLocation("lightPosition");
    location_lightColour = super.getUniformLocation("lightColour");
    System.out.println(location_transformationMatrix + " | "
            + location_lightPosition + " | " + location_lightColour);
}
public int getUniformLocation(String name){
    return GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, name);
}
```

However, when it prints out, it prints completely incorrectly:

```
0 | -1 | -1
```

`0` is for the fixed-function pipeline, so having something bound there is going to completely crash the program, and the other two are simply returning -1, which is a null value.

Here is my shader loading code:

```
public ShaderProgram(String vertexFile,String fragmentFile){
    System.out.println("Comiling shader!");
    vertexShaderID = loadShader(vertexFile,GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    fragmentShaderID = loadShader(fragmentFile,GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    programID = GL20.glCreateProgram();
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    bindAttributes();
    getAllUniformLocations();
    GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
    GL20.glValidateProgram(programID);
    start();
    System.out.println(GL11.glGetError());
    System.out.println("Comiled shader!");
}
```

The shaders bind, attach, validate, compile, etc, completely successfully, and the game does successfully run at this point. However, the uniform locations are missing and so I am unable to achieve things like lighting.

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 130

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
    surfaceNormal = (transformationMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;
    toLightVector = (vec3(0, 20000, 0)) - (transformationMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz;
}
```

Variables 0, 1, 2, and 3 are all bound to attributes, so I would expect the numbers to return something along the lines of "4 | 5 | 6".

Here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 130

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

uniform vec3 lightColour;

void main(void){
    vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
    vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector);

    float nDot1 = dot(unitNormal, unitLightVector);
    float brightness = max(nDot1, 0.5);
    brightness = brightness * 1.5;
    vec3 diffuse = brightness * vec3(1, 1, 1);
    vec4 text = texture(textureSampler, pass_textureCoords);
    vec4 textureColor = vec4(diffuse, 1.0) * text;
    if(textureColor.a<0.01){
        discard;
    }
    out_Color = vec4(textureColor.r, textureColor.g, textureColor.b, textureColor.a);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results you are getting are absoutely correct, your interpretations of them are not:

> `0` is for the fixed-function pipeline, so having something bound there
>   is going to completely crash the program,

No. `0` is a perfectly valid uniform location, which has nothing to do the fixed function pipeline. You somehow seem to confuse the program object `0` (which represents the fixed-function pipeline in legacy GL and compatibility profiles) with the *per-program* uniform locations.

> and the other two are simply
>   returning `-1`, which is a null value.

Well, more or less. `-1` means that there is no *acivte* uniform of that name. Note that calling `glUniform*()` functions with location `-1` is explicitely defined to be no error - such calls just have no effect.

The shader code you have pasted simply does not use the `lightPosition` and `lightColour` uniforms, so they are not there. You might intend to use them in the fragment shader, but I'd bet my life on it that you don't do it there in the correct way - i.e. even if you declare and use them in the code, they might still have no effect on the shader outputs, so are still not active.

Comment: But you seem to implying that everything is correct? If this is the case, why am I getting incorrect lighting, and in extreme cases, crashes?

Comment: @Joehot200: Both is rooted in the code you _didn't_ paste so far. The fragment shader would be really helpful for the lighting issue. The crash could be anything.

Comment: The crash explicitly occurs when calling `GL20.glUniformMatrix4(location, false, buf);`. The buffer is definitely not null, so why else would the issue be occurring? I have added the fragment shader to the question.

Comment: As for the uniform locations: you don't use `lightColour` in the fragment shader either. And you probably meant to use `lightPosition` in the vertex shader when calculation `toLightVector`, but you don't, so both uniforms are incorrect. As for the crash: hard to tell without context. Maybe `buf` is just not big enough to hold a 4x4 matrix. Or maybe something totally unrelated. You should start be explaining what exactly "cashing" means. Does the jre crash due to some access violation in the GL driver? Or is it throwing some java execpetion? Or something completely different?

Comment: Just so you know, on my pc only, *NOT* calling `getAllUniformLocations()` means that lighting works perfectly. The JRE crash does not happen on my own PC, and is due to an access violation. I'll pastebin the crash here: http://pastebin.com/qXmrTBN9 - For me, the game runs and lighting works 100%. For some people, the game works, but lighting does not. And for some others, it simply crashes as soon as the scene renders. I did a 4-hour testing session with my team, and we just couldn't solve the issue.

Comment: @Joehot200L there are lots of possible explanations for that. The lighting _can't_ work correctly in the sense that it would take `lightPosition` and `lightColour` into account, since oyur shaders don't do that at all. What might be the case on your PC is that the shaders fail to compile (or link) at all - which you never dare to check for, and you might get an implicit fallback for the fixed funbction pipeline. The usage of `ftransform()` in the shader is a strong hint that the drawing code might use the old builtin attributes, so it might as well use fixed-function lighting.

Comment: @Joehot200: for the crash: that is really hard to figure out without seeing the relevant code. You should create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have [moved this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93292/discussion-between-joehot200-and-derhass). I  think it would be a lot easier. .